# Database design: i have multiple type user and with different info

Tags: sql, database, entity-relationship

i development student register subject online system, but i have problem when i design database

i have three 3 user type

Admin (name,birth_day...etc)
Teacher(teacher_code,full_name,department....etc)
Student(student_code,fullname,class...etc)

now i design like picture

http://pik.vn/2014518006fd-061d-41dc-8b0b-195ae9c0677b.jpeg

i use MVC 5 ASP.NET.

problem 2: i have one subject"Math 3" t but student can register this subject if student learn required subject "Math 1" and subject "Math 2". best ideal for design it

my design for problem 2

http://pik.vn/201484fdcfd3-03b4-4486-97f3-6703c4561959.jpeg

Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

Add a 1:many relationship between Course and Prerequisite tables.  If a Student doesn't have all Prerequisite entries they can't sign up.